# Detecting Auto-Tuned tracks

Tags: windows, music

I am looking for a program that can take a music file as input (e.g. MP3) and output whether the voice of the singer (if any) has been auto-tuned. If possible, free, works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, takes several files as input.

Comment: Related question on Sound.SE : [How to recognize if Auto-Tune has been used in a recording? Is it needed?](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26892/how-to-recognize-if-auto-tune-has-been-used-in-a-recording-is-it-needed).

Comment: I think you would have to train some machine-learning system for the purpose. I'd be quite surprised to see packaged detectors for it.